# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in my View

Tags: php, codeigniter

Hi guys I have this block of code and the error Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file keeps on appearing my view. Can't seem to shake it off. any help guys. Thank you

```
<?php foreach($log->result() as $row): ?>
<?=form_open('admin/update_entry');?>
    <table class="editLog">
        <tr>
            <td><?php
                $data = array(
                    'name' => 'order',
                    'value' => $row->order
                );
                echo form_input($data);
                ?></td>
            <td><?php
                $data = array(
                    'name' => 'first',
                    'value' => $row->first
                );
                echo form_input($data);
                ?></td>
            <td><?php
                $data = array(
                    'name' => 'last',
                    'value' => $row->last
                );
                echo form_input($data);
                ?></td>
            <td><?php
                $data = array(
                    'name' => 'item',
                    'value' => $row->item
                );
                echo form_input($data);
                ?></td>
            <td><?php
                $data = array(
                    'name' => 'price',
                    'value' => $row->price
                );
                echo form_input($data);
                ?></td>
            <td>
            <?php
                echo form_hidden('id', $row->id);
                $data = array(
                    'class' => 'updateSubmit',
                    'value' => '✚'
                );
                echo form_submit($data);
            ?></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
<?=form_close();?>
```

Tried some solutions but to no avail. like the "short tag" removed it and the error still appears.

Answer (score 4):

You're missing the closing brace on your foreach statement. Something like:

```
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Generally speaking, *unexpected end of file* syntax errors imply that you are missing a brace somewhere, either for a conditional statement or a loop (i.e. while,foreach,do).

Comment: +1 This is most likely the issue.

Comment: Can also be the closing brace for a class or function as well.